# How to extract all IDs accessed from a mysql general log using the linux commandline?

Tags: mysql, bash, command-line, sed, awk

This should be a trivial question for anyone who's good with bash/sed/awk. Unfortunately, I'm not, yet :)

I've got a general log from MySQL which contains some queries that have a common parameter, they query on a specific id field. 
The queries look like

```
update tbl set col='binary_values' where id=X;
```

I need to process the log and extract all the IDs that these queries touched, each in it's own line. 
The purpose of this is to figure out how many times each ID is accessed. Eventually I'd group and count the values.
The binary values are indeed binary junk, so they kinda messed up some things I've been trying to do.

Eventually we solved the problem temporarily using a python script, but I'm sure the linux command line tool set can do it too. How would you do it?

Update (example of a query in the log):

```
5999 Query     update tbl set col='<AC><ED>\0^Ez\0\0^AaESC\0\0\0^D}k<85><F4>\0\0
c\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0^A\0\0\0^A\0^A\0\0\0^A\0^A\0\0\0^A\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0^A\0\0\0^Z^E^A<F6><DE>^A\0^A<F7><DE>^A\0^A<F8><DE>^A\0^A<F9><DE>^A\0^A<FE><DE>^A\0\0\0\0\0^A\0\0\0Q^E^C<C4>^O^A\0?<80>\0\0\0�°<C2><EA><D2>%^C<CB>^O^A\0?<80>\0\0\0�«<9C><CD><CC>%^C<EA>^Y^A\0?<80>\0\0\0�°<C2><EA><D2>%^C<90>^L^A\0?<80>\0\0\0�°<C2><EA><D2>%^C<F6>^L^A\0?<80>\0\0\0�«<9C><CD><CC>%\0^A\0\0\0T^E^D^A\0^A<83><D2>|^A<C4>^O\0�<D3>�³%^D^B\0^A�<B5>^B^A<F5>^K^A^R�<B2>�³%^D^A\0^A<FA>^L\0\0<AE><96><B1>�³%^D^A\0^A<F7>^W^A<90>^L^AESC<96><FC><B1>�³%^D^A\0^A^T^A<EA>^Y^A^F<F5>�±�³%\0\0\0\0\0\0\0^A\0\0\0^U^A^B\0\0\0\0\0\0^O9\0\0^A+<<87>u<E0>^A<85>^B^A\0\0\0^_^B^A^F^A\0?<80>\0\0\0�°<C2><EA><D2>%^AESC^A\0?<80>\0\0\0�°<C2><EA><D2>%\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0' where id=19284067828
```

The binary junk contains linebreaks as well as "=" characters, and makes it harder to use "cut".

Comment: Show me your flowchart and conceal your tables, and I shall continue to be mystified. Show me your tables, and I won't usually need your flowchart; it'll be obvious. (Meaning, show me an example of the output!)

Comment: The output would be something like:
123 4 \n
111 10 \n

The first one is the ID and the second one is the counter of how many times it appeared. A simple "group by" query, if you will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example log entry, this might work:

```
sed -n 's/.*update tbl set col=.*where id=\([0-9]\+\)$/\1/p' file.log
```

To count the occurrence of each id, you can pipe the output to `sort` and `uniq`

```
sed -n 's/.*update tbl set col=.*where id=\([0-9]\+\)$/\1/p' file.log | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what worked for me eventually (with a slight modification): 
> sed -n 's/^.* where id=\([0-9]\+\)$/\1/p' file.log | sort | unique -c

Answer (score 1):

It'd help if you copy pasted a couple if these queries, especially regarding the binary junk you talk about. but e.g.

```
grep "update tbl set col" yourfile.log | cut -d '=' -f 3  | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: This might just be it..., i'll test it and see if it gets the right results.

Comment: The cut command gets confused by the binary "junk". It sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't... I'll add an example of a query, but posting binary here won't work well...

Answer (score 0):

I would think create a `mod_date` timestamp column , default 0, on update set to current_timestamp (see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html))

To get list of updated records, you can easily find by filtering on `mod_date`

```
mod_date!=0  --> bindly get count

mod_date!=0 and mod_date>='since last log date'
```

Comment: I probably wasn't clear... 
I am actually interested in the number if IDs touched, specifically if it's the same ID. I had a suspicion that the application updates the same IDs several times in a row.

Comment: it still consider as single row get updated if the mod_date updated, or no?